# Get correct mouse position after zooming in/out an isometric map on HTML Canvas

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, html5-canvas

Hi I am trying to create isometric graphic app with React, mostly base on the code [here](https://codepen.io/zerratar/pen/GMjYyW).

I achieved most of the functions (ie. zoom and scroll).
But hovering tiles after zooming gives me wrong mouse position (hover position).

You can see what I mean [here](https://isometric-map.web.app/).
You can zoom with scrolling vertically.

When it is not zoomed in or out, hovering tile works correctly (tile color changes where the mouse positions).
But after zooming out/in it is not working right.

Does anyone know how to get the mouse position or tile index correctly after zooming in/out?

Implemented code can be found on my Github repo [here](https://github.com/masafumimori/Isometric-map)

Code snippet for getting target tile is below:

```
const handleHover = (x: number, y: number) => {
  const { e: xPos, f: yPos } = ctx.getTransform()
  const mouse_x = mouseRef.current.x - x - xPos
  const mouse_y = mouseRef.current.y - y - yPos

  const hoverTileX =
    Math.floor(
      mouse_y / Tile.TILE_HEIGHT + mouse_x / Tile.TILE_WIDTH
    ) - 1
  const hoverTileY = Math.floor(
     -mouse_x / Tile.TILE_WIDTH + mouse_y / Tile.TILE_HEIGHT
  )

  if (
    hoverTileX >= 0 &&
    hoverTileY >= 0 &&
    hoverTileX < gridSize &&
    hoverTileY < gridSize
  ) {
     const renderX =
        x + (hoverTileX - hoverTileY) * Tile.TILE_HALF_WIDTH
     const renderY =
        y + (hoverTileX + hoverTileY) * Tile.TILE_HALF_HEIGHT

     renderTileHover(ctx)(renderX, renderY + Tile.TILE_HEIGHT)
  }
}
```

I am not good at maths so I really need help...

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out how to achieve this.
I will leave it here so anyone who has the same issue wont waste a lot of time for this kind of issue.
My code is like this:

```
/**
 * @param context canvas context 2d
 * @param inputX mouse/touch input position x (ie. clientX)
 * @param inputY mouse/touch input position y (ie. clientY)
 * @returns {x, y} x and y position of inputX/Y which map scale and position are taken into account
 */
export const getTransformedPoint = (context: CanvasRenderingContext2D, inputX: number, inputY: number) => {
    const transform = context.getTransform()
    const invertedScaleX = DEFAULT_MAP_SCALE / transform.a
    const invertedScaleY = DEFAULT_MAP_SCALE / transform.d

    const transformedX = invertedScaleX * inputX - invertedScaleX * transform.e
    const transformedY = invertedScaleY * inputY - invertedScaleY * transform.f

    return { x: transformedX, y: transformedY }
}

/**
 *
 * @param startPosition position where map start rendered (Position2D has {x: number, y: number} type)
 * @param inputX mouse/touch input position x (ie. clientX)
 * @param inputY mouse/touch input position x (ie. clientY)
 * @returns positionX, positionY: tile position x, y axis
 */
export const getTilePosition = (
    startPosition: Position2D,
    inputX: number,
    inputY: number
): { positionX: number; positionY: number } => {
    const positionX =
        Math.floor((inputY - startPosition.y) / TILE_HEIGHT + (inputX - startPosition.x) / TILE_WIDTH) - 1
    const positionY = Math.floor(
        (inputY - startPosition.y) / TILE_HEIGHT - (inputX - startPosition.x) / TILE_WIDTH
    )

    return { positionX, positionY }
}

// usage
const onClick = (e: MouseEvent) => {

        const { x: mouseX, y: mouseY } = getTransformedPoint(ctx, e.clientX, e.clientY)

        const { positionX, positionY } = getTilePosition(startPositionRef.current, mouseX, mouseY)
        
        // Do something with positionX and positionY...
        // ie.
        if (return positionX >= 0 && positionY >= 0 && positionX < GRID_SIZE && positionY < GRID_SIZE) {
            // code when a user clicks a tile within the map
        }
    }
```

I referenced [this](https://roblouie.com/article/617/transforming-mouse-coordinates-to-canvas-coordinates/) for calculating the mouse position when the map is zoomed out/in.

Answer (score 0):

Try below

```
const handleHover = (x: number, y: number) => {
  // use the current scale of the canvas context
  const { a: scale, e: xPos, f: yPos } = ctx.getTransform()
  const mouse_x = (mouseRef.current.x - x - xPos) * scale
  const mouse_y = (mouseRef.current.y - y - yPos) * scale

  // rest of the code...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
But it doesn't work...
It was good to know we can get the current scale from `getTransform()` function thought.

Comment: Oh my bad. Hope someone else can help you out!